# Terraform test for null or false value of object key

Tags: terraform

Hopefully a relatively straightforward one. I have an object that uses the experimental optional attrs feature.

This means that one of the object attributes/keys do not need to be present. I then need to test for either null or false value of said object key in object composition with for loop.

When using the `module_variable_optional_attrs` experiment, it seems that if you use `lookup()` to find an object key which does not exist it'll always return null, not the default, as you might expect it to.

I now am having to test with a conditional `(lookup(connection, "auto_accept", false) == false || lookup(connection, "auto_accept", false) == null)`

this doesn't seem very clean. looking for suggestions on improvements.

**EDIT**

> main.tf

```
  terraform {
    # Optional attributes and the defaults function are
    # both experimental, so we must opt in to the experiment.
    experiments = [module_variable_optional_attrs]
  }

  variable "example_var" {
    type = list(object({
      name                   = string
      auto_accept            = optional(bool)
    }))
    description = "Some variable"
    default = [{
      name                   = "example-name"
    }]
  }
```

Below commands are run from `terraform console`

```
> lookup(var.example_var[0], "auto_accept")
false
# now lets make the key undefined
> lookup(var.example_var[0], "auto_accept")
tobool(null)
> lookup(var.example_var[0], "auto_accept", false)
tobool(null)
> tobool(null)
null
```

Comment: There is also `try` option.

Comment: `lookup` returns the default when the key does not exist, and not when the value does not exist. Aside from that, @MarkoE comment is correct answer.

Comment: @MarkoE `try` is no use since `try` would return both `null` if key undefined and false if key was defined but equal to `false`

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I added an edit to the post, which should shed some light on why `lookup()` is also not a suitable solution.

Comment: @David My comment explained why `lookup` would not work, and why you observed the behavior that you did. Also, I see now that you are looking for a conditional based on the truthiness of the value, and not a value resolution. Why not just `connection.auto_accept == null`?

Comment: @MattSchuchard because `false` is also a valid value of `connection.auto_accept` ? also, your explanation of lookup() isn't quite on the mark. since the key and the value do not exist if the optional object key is not specified. which is probably where the oddity to me has crept in. quite frankly, auto_accept could not be optional, and the problem goes away. friday fun

Comment: Ok then maybe approach this mathematically: since truthy values here are only `true` because the type is `bool`, and `falsey` are both `false` and `null`, then you can test against `true` instead of both `false` and `null`. As for the existence of the key: that has to do with Go map serialization and merging workarounds that I do not fully understand (and only really began succeeding in TF 0.13 despite the type introduction in 0.12 with HCL2), so I cannot really explain the reason for that too well because I do not 100% understand it myself.

Comment: A negative condition on bool `true` certainly could work. Where the original Q would simply become `lookup(connection, "auto_accept", false) != true`

Answer (score 0):

I have been in a similar scenario where I had following input map:

```
payload = {
  name     = "SomeTestName"
  optional_attr = "SomeOptionalAttribue"
}
```

The above payload could have following possible inputs:

```
payload = {
  name     = "SomeTestName"
  optional_attr = "SomeOptionalAttribue"
}
```

OR

```
payload = {
  name     = "SomeTestName"
}
```

OR

```
payload = {
  name     = "SomeTestName"
  optional_attr = null
}
```

My use case is to look for optional_attr in the payload and take its value as key and get corresponding value from the following map. If optional_attr is null or not provided then I take default value of mydefault key from the following map:

```
master_data = {
  optional_attr_value1     = "value1"
  optional_attr_value2     = "value2"
  mydefault                = "default_value"
}
```

Following combination of lookup with null check worked for me:

```
value = lookup(master_data, can(coalesce(payload.optional_attr)) ? lookup(tomap(payload), "optional_attr", "mydefault") : "mydefault" , "default_value")
```

What above code does is first it checks if optional_attr is not provided at all in the payload or its provided with a value of null. If this is true then the ternary statement returns false and "mydefault" value is provided that is used by outside lookup function to get mydefault key's corresponding value from master_data. If ternary operator returns true (optional_attry is provided with a value) then the internal lookup function is triggered and it will return value from master_data corresponding to whatever key provided as a value of optional_attr. Again if optional_attr value does not match any key in the master_data then default key of my_default is returned by internal lookup function.